# Access to the neighboring scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a few panels (ng-repeat) and respectively, I have a few scopes. A few scopes and few controllers.
When I close last panel (scope) I need refresh the data in last panel.

```
<div class="panel_block" ng-repeat="panel in content" ng-swipe-right="closeMainMenu()" ng-swipe-left="openMainMenu()">
    <div class="panel_in" onscroll="aaa()">
            <div panel-content
                 class="panel_in_panel"
                 addpanel="addpanel"
                 length="content.length"
                 lang="lang"
                 content="panel"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an update function in each controllers. But have can I run function from neighboring scope?

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I think $broadcast is what you need, details here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: As I know $broadcast dispatch an event downwards to all child scopes. But it's not child scope, it's next scope. (scope in ng-repeat). I should try catch this scope by angular.element($(".panel_block:last").find(".panel_in_panel")).scope()

Comment: well, you can call it via $rootScope, and all scope are children for root.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for your scenario:

- you could pass a callback to your panels that you trigger in your close method. The disadvantage of this approach is that you end up with some tight coupling between your components and the code can quickly become cluttered the more callbacks you begin passing around
- you could broadcast an event in your close method and have the other panels listen for this event. Here is a nice resource that explains how to do this (it's pretty straightforwards and with lots of examples): http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/